# Use XSS on a site, Dynamically

Tags: php, xss

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to check site's to be vulnerable to XSS dynamically, by using PHP. Are there solutions for this? Or is it just impossible and should it be done by hand?

Kevin

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically" here exactly? Whether the source code is created using PHP or by hand won't really matter, will it?

Comment: "input: www.example.org/form.php"
"output: yes, xss is possible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [OWASP Web Security Test](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Testing_Project) suite you can use for that other than other vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Kevin: For the *how* part, there is documentation of it here too :)

Comment: This is just a GUIDE, right? I was looking for a test-program or app that would check for those things, described in the GUIDE.